# NodeJS Mongoose & Mongo Db Connection Issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to mongodb and I have setup on mac os and it's successfully done. Now when I run my node js application with `mongoose` to connect with mongodb, It's always show a **connecting state**.

I am using below code to connect the database.

```
module.exports = function() {
    /**
     * Requiring this module will populate the mongoose connection pool.
     * Any models defined on mongoose will be ready to use (mongoose is
     * a singleton).
     */
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var logger = include('logger.js');

    // attempt to connect to the database server
  logger.info("DB CONNECTION ", {DB: global.settings.DB, options: global.settings.DbOptions});
  //console.log("DB CONNECTION ", {DB: global.settings.DB, options: global.settings.DbOptions});

    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/circleweb');
    mongoose.connection.on("open", function(ref) {
      console.log("Connected to mongo server.");
    });
    mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {
        console.log('connected');
        console.log('Mongoose default connection open to ' + global.settings.DB);
    });

    mongoose.connection.on('error', function (error) {
        logger.error(error);
        console.log('Mongoose default connection error: ' + error.err);

        // if the database cannot be connected to.  We are going to throw
        // an error.  This will be caught by the error handler
        throw error.err;
    });

    mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function () {
        console.log('Mongoose default connection disconnected');
    });

    process.on('SIGINT', function () {
        mongoose.connection.close(function () {
            console.log('Mongoose default connection disconnected through app termination');
            process.exit(0);
        });
    });

    console.log(mongoose.connection.readyState);
    return mongoose.connection;

}();
```

And When i run my application I am not getting any callback from `mongoose` not even any error.

Also when I run `mongod` on terminal it shows correct output and also it's accepting the connection from nodejs application but not connecting with it.

Any help would be appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Because `console.log(mongoose.connection.readyState)` is running synchronously - it will get executed first - before the `mongoose.connection.on` async calls, which means that the state is 2 or connecting.

Surround it with a timeout and you will get the expected 1 value:

```
setTimeout( () => {
  console.log(mongoose.connection.readyState); // prints 1
}, 2000);
```

Or print the state within the async call:

```
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {
  console.log(`STATE: `, mongoose.connection.readyState);
  console.log('connected');
  console.log('Mongoose default connection open to ' );
});
```

Comment: Yes, I have also try to log into `connected` event, You can see on above code but it's never going to that event.

Comment: Also I am getting this kind of log `connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:49709 #6 (1 connection now open)
` while I am trying to connect `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/circleweb` on port `27017`.

Comment: I have also tried the `timeout` but after that still it prints `2`

Comment: Okay, so sounds like that is not the issue then. Have you tried explicitly setting the port - `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/circleweb')`

Comment: yes, but no error saying.I found something that I need to run `node -gyp` for mongoose but nothing working